# Plurality of phrases describing categories of objects

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, category

When talking about a specific category of objects, does it make more sense to attach plurality to the label of the category, as in:

> Dogs are in the kingdom of animals, which also include cats.

or to attach singularity to the category itself, as in:

> Dogs are in the kingdom of animals, which also includes cats.

?

Comment: It's your attachment ambiguity; you can set it up any way you like. Each choice indicates a different attachment for the relative clause; singular verb agreement means that _which_ is coreferential to -- and the relative clause modifies -- _kingdom of animals_, while plural means that _which_ is coreferential to -- and the relative clause modifies -- _animals_. Either is possible, and it's completely ambiguous if modals are used: _the kingdom of animals, which can also include cats._
_

Comment: @JohnLawler Surely, an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The second one is correct in your case. Basically, the correct forms are:

For plural categories:

> All the categories **include** cats.

For plural members:

> This category **includes** cats and dogs.